# Upload file to amazon s3 using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire 4.0 to create a request to upload file directly to S3 Amazon.

I'm using the service from [GetCloudApp](http://getcloudapp.com). After my request `Router.shared.prepareForUploadItem` from an api `"https://my.cl.ly/v3/items` I retrieve the json like this

```
{
  "slug": "1h132K0z2n3G",
  "name": "Image.png",
  "url": "http://f.cl.ly",
  "uploads_remaining": 1,
  "max_upload_size": 26214400,
  "s3": {
    "AWSAccessKeyId": "AKIAJP2C6U543KJIE2GA",
    "key": "items/353u2B053p0H0D1O3w1b/${filename}",
    "policy": "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMS0xMlQxMjo0MTozOFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJjbG91ZGFwcC5jb3BwZXIuaW8ifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJGtleSIsIml0ZW1zLzM1M3UyQjA1M3AwSDBEMU8zdzFiLyJdLHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiJodHRwOi8vbXkuY2wuZGV2L3YzL2l0ZW1zLzFoMTMySzB6Mm4zRy9zMyJ9LHsiYWNsIjoicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSxbImNvbnRlbnQtbGVuZ3RoLXJhbmdlIiwwLDI2MjE0NDAwXV19",
    "signature": "wqSVl9+fvkvtIzGfakNF+drqN0s=",
    "success_action_redirect": "http://api.cl.ly/v3/items/1h132K0z2n3G/s3",
    "acl": "public-read"
  }
}
```

I take these `key` and `value` as my parameter :

```
"AWSAccessKeyId": "AKIAJP2C6U543KJIE2GA",
"key": "items/353u2B053p0H0D1O3w1b/${filename}",
"policy": "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMS0xMlQxMjo0MTozOFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJjbG91ZGFwcC5jb3BwZXIuaW8ifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJGtleSIsIml0ZW1zLzM1M3UyQjA1M3AwSDBEMU8zdzFiLyJdLHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiJodHRwOi8vbXkuY2wuZGV2L3YzL2l0ZW1zLzFoMTMySzB6Mm4zRy9zMyJ9LHsiYWNsIjoicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSxbImNvbnRlbnQtbGVuZ3RoLXJhbmdlIiwwLDI2MjE0NDAwXV19",
"signature": "wqSVl9+fvkvtIzGfakNF+drqN0s=",
"success_action_redirect": "http://api.cl.ly/v3/items/1h132K0z2n3G/s3",
"acl": "public-read"
```

Then I create the request to upload my file using `s3` dictionary like below :

```
 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartForm) in

  for (key, value) in parameter {

    let valueData = value.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

    guard let newData = valueData else{
      return
    }

    multipartForm.append(newData, withName: key)

    print("\(key) - \(value)")
  }

  multipartForm.append(data, withName: "file")

}, to: s3.url, method : .post) { (encodingResult) in

  switch encodingResult {
  case .success(let upload, _, _):
    upload.responseJSON { response in
      debugPrint(response)
    }
  case .failure(let encodingError):
    print(encodingError)
  }
}
```

Finally I retrieve the response from server like this, I know it all about authentication but I really don't know what's the right way to do that.

```
status code: 401, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 28;
"Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sun, 08 Jan 2017 17:37:17 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
Status = "401 Unauthorized";
"Www-Authenticate" = "Digest realm=\"Application\", qop=\"auth\", algorithm=MD5, nonce=\"MTQ4Mzg5NzAzNzpiYmEwN2MzZDljM2RjNDMyMGE1NzI2ODQ5MjhjMWVkNQ==\", opaque=\"9eb56ccb2e8b017ae42bdb4739690863\"";
"X-Request-Id" = 7bd77581bf677aee1b1abba21b3ad097;
"X-Runtime" = "0.004697";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
```

I try many ways but still no luck and can't make it work. I really need help. Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you creating the signature yourself? or relying on Alamofire?

Comment: Hi, the signature are supporting by CloudApp Services. I figured out what's my problem. Check my answer below please. Thank for asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why this problem is occurred because I need to authenticate my upload request to S3 using `CloudApp`'s Digest authenticate after my request to `CloudApp` to upload new file.

I will posted my completed code below:

```
func uploadFileToS3(_ s3: S3, data : Data, fileName : String, mimeType : String) {

let params = s3.s3Parameter

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartForm) in

  for (key, value) in params{

    multipartForm.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)

  }

  multipartForm.append(data, withName: "file", fileName: fileName, mimeType: mimeType)

}, to: s3.url, method : .post, headers:["Accept":"application/json"]) { (encodingResult) in

  guard let userInfor = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "UserInformation") else {
    return
  }

  switch encodingResult {
  case .success(let upload, _, _):
    upload.authenticate(user: userInfor["email"]! as! String, password: userInfor["password"]! as! String)

    self.progressbar.isHidden = false
    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

      self.progressbar.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)

    })

    upload.responseJSON{ response in

      self.progressbar.isHidden = true

      let result = JSON(response.result.value!)
      let file = CloudFile(fileInformation: result)

      self.files.append(file)

      let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.filesTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
      }

    }
  case .failure(let encodingError):
    print(encodingError)
  }
}
```

}

Noticed `upload.authenticate(user: userInfor["email"]! as! String, password: userInfor["password"]! as! String)` in `encodingResult` result completion handle, this is where you need authenticate your upload request. Alamofire will do the rest.

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: @sunsunai do you have any instructions on the authentication part?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral Hi, I'm sorry cause I'm not really checking my stackoverflow comment haha, btw thank for asking.

Actually I don't understand what's instructions mean in your question ? You mean is knowledge about authentication part ? If yes, I must say that I learn everything by myself and don't have any based knowledge about that.

Comment: Thank you! In case anyone needs this, follow this answer for an updated syntax for Alamofire https://stackoverflow.com/a/69273951/6548566

Also, you can set the Content-Type like this:

multipartForm.append(Data("image/jpeg".utf8), withName: "Content-Type")