# Swift Alamofire multipart form data URLRequest has no member failure

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to hook up image uploading in my application. I am using Alamofire and the `multipartFormData` functionality within Alamofire to achieve this.

I have my function written to upload this image along with other attributes.

```
func savePreferences(parameters: [String:Any], image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (Response?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = "http://localhost:3000/users/3b4e124d-3b3c-4c71-8e05-013e461c2892"
    let imgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!

    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "profile_imgname",fileName: "ProfilePic_\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_id") ?? "").jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, to: url, method: .patch) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if let err = response.error {
                    failure(err)
                    return
                }
                completion(response.result.value)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

In the `switch` statement at the end, in the `case .success` and `case .failure`, I am receiving the following error:

> Type 'URLRequest' has no member 'failure'

> Type 'URLRequest' has no member 'success'

I have used existing Stack Overflow resources to understand how this `multipartFormData` works, and it seems that they follow this format to an extent.

Please see below:

[Send POST parameters with MultipartFormData using Alamofire, in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949118/send-post-parameters-with-multipartformdata-using-alamofire-in-ios-swift)

[How to upload pictures with Alamofire (post)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417347/how-to-upload-pictures-with-alamofire-post)

Why am I getting the errors with `URLRequest has no member failure` and how can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alamofire 5.0 migration document says this:

> `MultipartFormData`’s API has changed and the top level upload methods to create and upload MultipartFormData have been updated to match other request APIs, so it’s not longer necessary to deal with the Result of the multipart encoding.

(https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%205.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

The code that you're using looks to be from an earlier version. In 5.0, the trailing closure uses a `URLRequest` as its parameter (explaining the errors that you're seeing).

The Usage guide (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md) provides this as an example of uploading multipart form data:

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(Data("one".utf8), withName: "one")
    multipartFormData.append(Data("two".utf8), withName: "two")
}, to: "https://httpbin.org/post")
    .responseDecodable(of: HTTPBinResponse.self) { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

(`HTTPBinResponse` is an example of a `Decodable` that you can replace with your own).

Besides `responseDecodable`, it looks like you can also use `responseJSON`, `responseData`, `responseString` etc.

Note that all of these are appended with a `.` *after* the closing `)` of the call -- not as a trailing closure.